# Cannot convert lambda expression into delegate type

Tags: c#, lambda, delegates

I have a method like this:

```
public ICollection<T> GetEntitiesWithPredicate(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
{
           // ...
}
```

I do a method call in another class like

```
service.GetEntitiesWithPredicate(x => x.FoobarCollection.Where(y => y.Text.Contains(SearchText)));
```

but I always get this error:

```
Lambda expression cannot be converted to '<typename>' because '<typename>' is not a delegate type
```

What do I have to change to get this work?

Edit:

I use Entity Framework 6 and if I use Any() instead of Where(), I always get only 1 result back... I want to pass the expression to my EF-implementation:

```
    public ICollection<T> GetEntriesWithPredicate(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
    {
        using (var ctx = new DataContext())
        {
            return query.Where(predicate).ToList();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You probably meant `Any()` instead of `Where()`. Your `Func<T, bool>` needs to return `bool` but `Where` is returning `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: those aren't compatible.

Comment: Are you sure you mean `GetEntitiesWithPredicate(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)`and not just `GetEntitiesWithPredicate(Func<T, bool>predicate)`? Why do you need the `Expression`?

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider, Because in the method implementation, the predicate is being passed to some Linq provider (like Entity Framework)

Comment: @haim770 could you check my edit, please

Comment: @GrayFox, A "predicate" (by definition) needs to return `bool`. If by using `Any()` you're only getting a single entity then it's the only entity that is having 1 or more of the items in its `FoobarCollection` that contains your `SearchText`.

Comment: @haim770 I know, can I overload my GetEntities-Method to accept .Where() LINQs which are compatible with EF?

Comment: @GrayFox, Your existing method already wraps the internal `Where()` call to Entity Framework...

Comment: @haim770, my approach doesn't work. I want the ability to pass Where expressions that EF executes this against my DB...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100376/discussion-between-grayfox-and-haim770).

Comment: Any() or Where() seems unnecessary, it is confusing that you need to access a collection at all from your expression delegate. It seems to me that you ideally would want usage to really just look like this... service.GetEntitiesWithPredicate(x =>  x.Text.Contains(SearchText));

Answer (score 0):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var o = new Foo { };

        var f = o.GetEntitiesWithPredicate(a => a.MyProperty.Where(b => b.MyProperty > 0).ToList().Count == 2); // f.MyProperty == 9 true
    }
}

class Foo
{
    public ICollection<T> GetEntitiesWithPredicate(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
    {
        var t = predicate.Compile();

        var d = t.Invoke(new T { MyProperty = new List<Y> { new Y { MyProperty = 10 }, new Y { MyProperty = 10 } } });



        if (d) return new List<T> { new T { MyProperty = new List<Y> { new Y { MyProperty = 9 } } } };

        return null;
    }
}

class T
{
    public T() { }
    public List<Y> MyProperty { get; set; }
}

class Y
{
    public int MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```